# extendscript after effects why isnt my list items not adding

Tags: extendscript

why are my Listbox items not added? to Listbox, I don't get it.

the code looks ok just did some modification to the new instance of GUI and now my Listbox items not adding

not sure where the error is just testing as i await your response from all you pros.

feel free to run this and test it and kindly point out the issue thanks.

```
gridder.buildGUI =function(thisObj){
dialog = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new Window("palette", thisObj.scriptTitle, undefined, {resizeable:true});
     
    var w = dialog;
dialog.text = "ALL IN ONE TOOLBOX 2022"; 
dialog.preferredSize.width = 180; 
dialog.preferredSize.height = 520; 
dialog.orientation = "column"; 
dialog.alignChildren = ["fill","top"]; 
dialog.spacing = 10; 
dialog.margins = 16; 



var tpanel = dialog.add("tabbedpanel", undefined, undefined, {name: "tpanel"}); 
tpanel.alignChildren = "fill"; 
tpanel.preferredSize.width = 348; 
tpanel.margins = 0; 

// CLRTAB
// ======


var Main = tpanel.add("tab", undefined, undefined, {name: "clrTab"}); 
Main.text = "Main"; 
Main.orientation = "column"; 
Main.alignChildren = ["fill","top"]; 
Main.spacing = 10; 
Main.margins = 10; 

// CLRTAB_LSTGRP
// =============
var clrTab_LstGrp = Main.add("group", undefined, {name: "clrTab_LstGrp"}); 
//clrTab_LstGrp.orientation = "row"; 
clrTab_LstGrp.alignChildren = ["left","center"]; 
clrTab_LstGrp.spacing = 10; 
clrTab_LstGrp.margins = 0; 


var t = Main.add("statictext", undefined, "Hello", {multiline:false});
t.text = "Create Solids";
t.graphics.foregroundColor = t.graphics.newPen (t.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 1);
t.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Arial", "Bold", 30);

var listBoxxa = Main.add("listbox", undefined, undefined, {name: "listBoxxa", items: listBoxxa_array}); 
listBoxxa.preferredSize.width = 300; 
listBoxxa.size = [100, 130];

 var listBoxxa_array = [
"Create 2 solids",
"Create Solid",
"Create Solid with fractual noise",
"Create Solid CC Particle World",
"Create Solid Particular",
"Solid With BCC Sphere",
"Solid With BCC Turbulence",
 ]; 
 


    if (dialog instanceof Window){
        dialog.center();
        dialog.show();
    }
    else dialog.layout.layout(true);
};


gridder.buildGUI(gridder);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Listbox you haven't yet initialised `listBoxxa_array`. So when you create the control object you're giving it an undefined variable as its contents. Move the section where you define `listBoxxa_array` above the line where you define `listBoxxa`.